# Geo plugin API is not working on a domain sometimes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, geo

I've used geo plugin(http://www.geoplugin.com/) api to get currency of the country using user's ip address. It seems to be working on last week. But sometimes it gives wrong response(ie it is not working for our domain).Is the server blocking our domain? Can anyone help on this?

Comment: what javascript are you using, and what exactly is the error message returned? how frequently does it happen? does it occur at times of peak usage? some services will block a domain if you hit it too many times in too short a timespan in order to get you to cough up some cash, so might look into that,

Comment: I'm using the the following link (http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR') to get the response.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the actual JS method which calls the service (obfuscating any IDs or keys ) in a code block? Can you answer my other questions? Is the issue sporadic or constant? does it occur at times of peak usage, or at random times through the day? have you checked the service for any usage limits? From their website they only allow up to 100,000 requests per day without prior contact, and 120 requests per minute, after which you get a 403 error for a period of 1 hour. How do you use the service?

Comment: their user agreement: http://www.geoplugin.com/aup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks  user1666620

I got the answer from http://www.geoplugin.com/aup. The issue occurs at times of peak usage.